# php can't load php5-memcached extension

Tags: debian-jessie, php-memcached

I have an issue with the php5-memcached process install.

My Debian version : 8.5

My php version : PHP 5.6.24-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Jul 26 2016 08:17:07)

I have made `apt-get install php5-memcached` but the module is not loaded.

`php -m` don't return the `memcached` module in result.

In my error logs, there is the following message :

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/memcached.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/memcached.so: undefined symbol: memcached_destroy_sasl_auth_data in Unknown on line 0
```

In my `/etc/php5/cli` directory, the file 2`0-memcached.ini` exists. In `/usr/lib/php5/20131226`, the file `memcached.so` exists.

I have several servers with debian and php and I don't have this issue. It's strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is php-memcached bug, which was [fixed in their git tree](https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/pull/219). Consider installing module with pecl/building from git.

```
# git clone https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached
# cd php-memcached
# phpize
# ./configure
# make
# make test
```

Comment: Thank you. I have installed it as you explain and it works.